# call update action from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controllers: `ControllerA` and `ControllerB`.

Is it possible to call the `ControllerA.update` function from `ControllerB`? Something as demonstrated below:

```
class ControllerB < ApplicationController
  def foo
    ControllerA.update args
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call another class method of another controller as any other classes. Actions are defined as instance methods and you should therefore instantiate a controller just by doing `ControllerA.new`.

That said, you shouldn't do that. I strongly discourage to got that road, that is not how the controllers are meant to be used.

If some logic in your application are to be shared between controllers, put it elsewhere, maybe in a model or a service (or something else) depending of what you want to achieve.

Comment: The protected section of application.rb (if you want it in all controllers), or in a module in lib (which is included in the controllers you want to have the method), is an appropriate place for shared controller code.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not call it directly, but you can `redirect` to another controller action.

Comment: Yes, see [redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) for all possible options.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You can redirect to that controller's function.

I don't know what you want to do in that update, but check if you cannot insert that function into "aModel".